# How to fix OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use

Tags: python, django

I am working this [book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch08.html#_as_always_start_with_a_test)

using this code

```
    @classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    for arg in sys.argv:
        if 'liveserver' in arg:
            cls.server_url = 'http://' + arg.split('=')[1]
            return
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.server_url=cls.live_server_url
```

When I try to start my functional tests with python3 manage.py test functional_tests I get this error

```
ERROR: setUpClass (functional_tests.tests.NewVisitorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/dev/tddwp/chap8/functional_tests/tests.py", line 14, in setUpClass
    super().setUpClass()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1189, in setUpClass
    raise cls.server_thread.error
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1091, in run
    (self.host, port), QuietWSGIRequestHandler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 117, in __init__
    super(WSGIServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 430, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 121, in server_bind
    super(WSGIServer, self).server_bind()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/server.py", line 135, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 441, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

I have tried
*rebooting my machine
*downloading the repo off github and running from there to eliminate any inadvertent errors I may have made
*using [lsof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703797/need-to-close-python-socket-find-the-current-running-server-on-my-dev-environm) to see if I can find the port it is running on and kill it (I can't find it).

I am out of ideas.  Anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: maybe use different port - with big number - like 8000

Comment: That means something else is already listening on that port. Probably another web server. Try using a different port.

Comment: Have you ever figured it out? I get this error after I quit my own server with Crtl-C.

Comment: @MadPhysicist They were right, use a different port.  Somehow I forgot to close this.  Sorry.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use a different port :D.  As per furas and Keith